# Centrar MENU Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, css3

mi código HTML es el siguiente:

```css
.nav-header {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 20px;
}

#fh5co-menu-wrap .sf-menu a {
  padding: 1em .75em;
}
```

```html
<div id="fh5co-wrapper">
    <div id="fh5co-page">
    <div id="fh5co-header">
        <header id="fh5co-header-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-header">
                    <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
                    <!-- <h1 id="fh5co-logo"><a href="index.html">Show<span>IT</span></a></h1> -->
                    <!-- START #fh5co-menu-wrap -->
                    <nav id="fh5co-menu-wrap" role="navigation">
                        <ul class="sf-menu" id="fh5co-primary-menu">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#servicios" class="fh5co-sub-ddown">Servicios</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#proyectos" class="fh5co-sub-ddown">Equipo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

He estado intentando modificar la clase .nav-header pero realmente no he conseguido centrarlo. Si alguien puede ayudarme, realmente lo agradecería. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Cuando dices "centrar" no queda claro a que te refieres... ¿centrar al centro de la página? ¿en una sola línea o en varias?

Comment: Centrar al medio de la página, exactamente. Obviamente de manera horizontal, que quede en la misma barra de menu pero al centro.

Comment: En ese caso tienes que decir que el ul mide por ejemplo 200px y luego un margin:0 auto lo centrará, sería: .sf-menu { width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: Encontre que el menu tiene todo esto: 
/* Superfish Override Menu */

.sf-menu {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.sf-menu {
  float: right;
}

.sf-menu ul {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: transparent;
  min-width: 12em;
  *width: 12em;
}

.sf-menu a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 0.75em 1em !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-top: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  zoom: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
.sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:focus {
  color: #fff !important;
}

Comment: .sf-menu li.active a:hover, .sf-menu li.active a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.sf-menu li,
.sf-menu ul li,
.sf-menu ul ul li,
.sf-menu li:hover,
.sf-menu li.sfHover {
  background: transparent;
}

.sf-menu ul li a,
.sf-menu ul ul li a {
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 0.25em 1em !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.sf-menu li:hover a,
.sf-menu li.sfHover a,
.sf-menu ul li:hover a,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover a,
.sf-menu li.active a {
  color: #fff;
}

.sf-menu ul li:hover,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover {
  background: transparent;
}

Comment: .sf-menu ul li {
  background: transparent;
}

Comment: PROBE LO QUE VOS ME DIJISTE, PERO NO FUNCIONÓ. ALGUNA CLASE DE ESTAS ME DEBE ESTAR PISANDO

Comment: He hehco la prueba en vivo en esta misma página en tu propio código y si funciona, te pondría la respuesta, pero no es una buena pregunta y probablemente será cerrada. Si quieres edito el código de tu propia pregunta para que lo veas, después te recomiendo borrar la pregunta.

Comment: Bueno dale. Podrias modificar el código mio, lo veo y borro la publicacion? Gracias

Comment: Ya lo tienes, si le das a ejecutar, verás que el menú está centrado, supongo que a parte de eso, tendrás que hacer algunos arreglos más, como poner los elementos en línea, en ese caso, deberás aumentar el width. Lo de borrar la pregunta es una sugerencia, tal vez no debas borrarla, no lo sé.

Comment: Eso no está centrado. Necesito centrado de manera horizontal, al medio de la pagina.

Comment: Y así estaba, ¿puedes explicarlo con otras palabras? ¿no te vale la respuesta de AsieR_2? su resultado también sale centrado horizontalmente.

Comment: Sale centrado al medio (perfecto), pero los menu van para abajo y tienen que ir uno al lado del otro

Answer (score 2):

Como no me queda claro a qué te refieres con centrar, asumo que lo quieres poner en línea pues un menú como ese en el centro no tendría excesivo sentido. (Al menos en formato de escritorio.)

Añadir al CSS:

```
#fh5co-menu-wrap ul li {
  display:inline;
}
```

Deberás retirar la propiedad `bottom` del .nav-header. (Que además está repetida.)

**EDICIÓN PARA LA RESPUESTA**

```css
    .nav-header {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 100;
      bottom: 20px;
    }

    #fh5co-menu-wrap .sf-menu a {
      padding: 1em .75em;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="fh5co-wrapper">
        <div id="fh5co-page">
        <div id="fh5co-header">
            <header id="fh5co-header-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="nav-header">
                        <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
                        <!-- <h1 id="fh5co-logo"><a href="index.html">Show<span>IT</span></a></h1> -->
                        <!-- START #fh5co-menu-wrap -->
                        <nav id="fh5co-menu-wrap" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="sf-menu" id="fh5co-primary-menu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#servicios" class="fh5co-sub-ddown">Servicios</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#proyectos" class="fh5co-sub-ddown">Equipo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
```

Comment: Es centrar el menu al centro del navegador, como que no tiene sentido?. Centrar de manera horizontal, no vertical

Comment: #fh5co-menu-wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 22px;
}
#fh5co-menu-wrap .sf-menu a {
  padding: 1em .75em;
}

Comment: Esos son los atributos que tienen esas dos clases

Comment: ¿Estamos hablando en versión de escritorio o en la de móviles?

Comment: Versión de escritorio :/

Comment: Quieres un menú vertical (como el que tienes ahora) pero arriba, en el centro de la pantalla?

Comment: Lo he editado, si sigue sin ser lo que buscas intenta ser más claro.

Comment: Bien, ahí está en el medio pero no tiene que ir escalonado para abajo, sino uno al lado del otro! Gracias querido

Answer (score 2):

Recomendaría usar `display: inline-block` de esa forma a parte de `padding` podrás usar `margin` también y le dará más flexibilidad al diseño.

Además, hay que recordar que trabajando con elementos *inline* los retornos de carro en el código se consideran caracteres, por lo que ocupan un espacio no controlado. Para solucionarlo y mantener el sangrado (indentado) del HTML se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```html
<style>
    #fh5co-menu-wrap {
       font-size: 0; /*escondemos todo el texto contenido, incluido los espacios*/
    }
    #fh5co-menu-wrap ul li {
       display:inline-block;
       font-size: 1rem; /*damos el tamaño al texto de los items del menú*/
margin: 2px;
       padding: .75em;
       border: solid 1px #ccc;
       
    }
   .nav-header {
       /*position: relative;
       float: left;
       width: 100%;
       z-index: 100;
       bottom: 20px;*//*Estoy convencido que todo este código es prescindible y/o se puede solucionar de alguna manera más sencilla*/
    }
    /*#fh5co-menu-wrap .sf-menu a {
       padding: 1em .75em;
    }*//*Pasamos el padding al li padre*/
    ul {
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       width: 500px;
       text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div id="fh5co-wrapper">
    <div id="fh5co-page">
        <div id="fh5co-header">
            <header id="fh5co-header-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="nav-header">
                        <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
                        <nav id="fh5co-menu-wrap" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="sf-menu" id="fh5co-primary-menu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#servicios" class="fh5co-sub-ddown">Servicios</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#proyectos" class="fh5co-sub-ddown">Equipo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El código de AsierR es bueno, añado las modificaciones oportunas para mostrar los elementos en la misma línea y de forma centrada horizontalmente:

```html
<style>
    #fh5co-menu-wrap ul li {
        display:inline;
    }
   .nav-header {
       position: relative;
       float: left;
       width: 100%;
       z-index: 100;
       bottom: 20px;
    }
    #fh5co-menu-wrap .sf-menu a {
       padding: 1em .75em;
    }
    ul {
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       width: 500px;
       text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div id="fh5co-wrapper">
    <div id="fh5co-page">
        <div id="fh5co-header">
            <header id="fh5co-header-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="nav-header">
                        <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
                        <nav id="fh5co-menu-wrap" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="sf-menu" id="fh5co-primary-menu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#servicios" class="fh5co-sub-ddown">Servicios</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#proyectos" class="fh5co-sub-ddown">Equipo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto realmente era !! Voy a ver si me funciona, porque como comenté antes, hay muchas clases y quizás se están superponiendo unas sobre otras

Comment: .sf-menu {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.sf-menu {
  float: right;
}

.sf-menu ul {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: transparent;
  min-width: 12em;
  *width: 12em;
}

.sf-menu li,
.sf-menu ul li,
.sf-menu ul ul li,
.sf-menu li:hover,
.sf-menu li.sfHover {
  background: transparent;
}

.sf-menu ul li a,
.sf-menu ul ul li a {
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 0.25em 1em !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.sf-menu li:hover a,
.sf-menu li.sfHover a,
.sf-menu ul li:hover a,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover a,
.sf-menu li.active a {
  color: #fff;
}

Comment: .sf-menu ul li:hover,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover {
  background: transparent;
}

.sf-menu ul li {
  background: transparent;
}

Comment: Ya está o quieres decirnos lago con ese código?